# Displaying Multiple SQL Fields as a Single Field

Tags: sql, mysql, join, view

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE title (
 booktitle VARCHAR( 60 ),
 title_id CHAR( 6 ),
 au_id CHAR( 11 ),
 PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
    )

 create table authors (
 au_id  char(11),
 au_lname varchar(20),
 au_fname varchar(20),
 phone  varchar(10),
 address  varchar(30),
 city  varchar(20),
 state  char(2),
 zip  char(5));
```

I need to somehow show the booktitle, au_lname and au_fname in one field.
I want to order it by CITY, but that should be simple enough.
So far I have made a view of this data, but I am not sure how to make it into a single field? I tried using the "AS" command, but I keep getting errors.

Here is my working view:

```
CREATE VIEW authorname AS
 SELECT
  title.booktitle, authors.au_fname, authors.au_lname
 FROM
  title
  INNER JOIN authors ON title.au_id = authors.au_id
 ORDER BY authors.city
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate string values:

```
CREATE VIEW authorname AS
  SELECT
    CONCAT(title.booktitle,  authors.au_fname,  authors.au_lname) as name
  FROM title
  INNER JOIN authors ON title.au_id = authors.au_id
  ORDER BY authors.city
```

or if you want to separate the values by a certain character, use [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', title.booktitle,  authors.au_fname, authors.au_lname) as name
```

Comment: I simply used  CONCAT(titles.title, ' - ',  authors.au_fname, ' ',  authors.au_lname) as name -- Thanks again!